# Parser erro em Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Em minha `view`, `welcome.blade.php` estou recebendo um erro de parser no seguinte trecho HTML:

```
<div class="single_service_left">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/flaticon4.png') }}" alt="" />
</div>
```

Até então me parece perfeitamente normal, mas o erro a seguir é apresentado:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>" alt="" />' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

E o `debugger` aponta para a linha que seria "parseada" da seguinte maneira;

```
<div class="single_service_left">
    <img src="<?php echo e(asset('images/flaticon4.png')); ?>" alt="" />
</div>
```

A versão do PHP que estou utilizando é a `7.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema; o mesmo era gerado por um erro de syntax que vinha de outro componente importado dentro do html em questão.

Como o laravel compilava tudo em um unico arquivo parecia que o erro era do arquivo "X" mas na verdade era de um `@include` de outro html.